# Win service to install another win service (programmatically in C#?)

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a win service running under the system session. I want this main service to control (install/remove) another winservice to be installed under another user (we main service have the user/password).
How to do that?

Comment: Could this work?
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl, string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);

Answer (score 1):

What you are intending to do sounds a bit hackish, but if you really want to do it then you can by using the [sc.exe utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251192) that is bundled with Windows. All you have to do is make sure the correct service files are in place on the file system (for example under `%PROGRAMFILES%\[CompanyName]\[ServiceName]`), then use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to invoke sc.exe with the right command line arguments.

To specify the name and password for the account the service should run under, use the `obj= <account name>` and `password= <password>` options. Note the space between the option and its value - without that space the command will fail.

Another option is to use Process.Start() to invoke [installutil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is part of the .Net framework). A quick example of this is:

```
var installutil = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) 
                + "\\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\installutil.exe";
var arguments = string.Format( " /ServiceName=\"{0}\" /DisplayName=\"{1}\" \"{2}\" ", 
                               serviceName, 
                               displayName, 
                               servicePath);
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(installutil, arguments)  {
                                                            CreateNoWindow = true,
                                                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                                            RedirectStandardInput = false,
                                                            RedirectStandardError = false,
                                                            ErrorDialog = false,
                                                            UseShellExecute = false
                                                        };

var p = new Process { StartInfo = psi, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it if my way not works, I do not like to run 3rd party (even if it is Microsoft) process from my win service. Could someone change it/virus, and I will execute it with system privileges!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all I need in my main win service to call:

```
//Installs and starts the service
ServiceInstaller.InstallAndStart("MyServiceName", "MyServiceDisplayName", "C:\PathToServiceFile.exe");
```

And make sure inside the target (the one I want to control/install) Service code (ServiceInstaller) the right Installer:

```
  public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;
        private ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller;

        public MyServiceInstaller()
        {
            // instantiate installers for process and service
            processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            // run under the system service account
            processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
            processInstaller.Username = ".\\UserName";
            processInstaller.Password = "password";

            // service to start automatically.
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            serviceInstaller.Description = "MyServiceDescription";

            // name
            string SvcName = "MyServiceNae";

            // ServiceName must equal those on ServiceBase derived classes
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = SvcName;

            // displayed in list
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "My Service DisplayName ";

            // add installers to collection
            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
            Installers.Add(processInstaller);
            Committed += new InstallEventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {
                var controller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(SvcName);
                controller.Start();
            });
        }
    }
```

The installandstart:

```
  public static void InstallAndStart(
            string serviceName,
            string displayName,
            string fileName,
            string username=null,
            string password = null)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(null, null, ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);
            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(
                    scm,
                    serviceName,
                    ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    service = CreateService(
                        scm,
                        serviceName,
                        displayName,
                        ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess,
                        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                        ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart,
                        ServiceError.Normal,
                        fileName,
                        null,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        null,
                        username,
                        password);

                    if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install service.");

                    try
                    {
                        StartService(service, 0, 0);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        CloseServiceHandle(service);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }
```